# How to resize active accordion header on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, accordion

I have an accordion using the W3.CSS framework. I want to resize the showing accordion headers (not collapsing panels) on click so that in addition to opening the collapsing panel, the header grows. In the accordion the headers are created from buttons. The background of these buttons is a picture filling using the cover style in CSS. I want the buttons to be sized to show the entire image. I am using the pseudo class :hover on the buttons and its working fine, but I can't get an :active class, pseudo OR applied with javascript to resize the button. Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

**HTML**

```
<div class = "hello">
<a id="edge">
<a href="#edge"><button id="edge" onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black w3-left-align"><h2 class="title">EDGE</h2></button></a>
</div>

<div id="Demo1" class="w3-hide">
<div class="w3-container">
```

The "w3-black" class I kept to try to use the W3.CSS framework activating method which is [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_accordions.asp).

**FUNCTION**

I know this is using "replace", its the latest thing that I've tried.

```
function myFunction(id) {
var x = document.getElementById(id);
if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
    x.previousElementSibling.className = 
x.previousElementSibling.className.replace("w3-black", "w3-red");
} else { 
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    x.previousElementSibling.className = 
x.previousElementSibling.className.replace("w3-red", "w3-black");
}
}
```

**CSS**

I haven't transformed the size at all, just have been testing out the opacity to see if I could get the function to work.

```
#edge {
background-image: url(Pictures/Edge/Edge-Devices-Mockup.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 16.67vh;
} 

.w3-black {
opacity: 1;
}

.w3-black:hover {
opacity: .5;
}

.w3-red {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Hoping someone can let me know where I went wrong! Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a working snippet, here or by link? it would help a lot

Comment: SNIPPET ADDED @CalvinNunes  https://jsfiddle.net/06p8b2zn/9/

Comment: I opened the snippet, but if i'm not worng, there is some tags that open but are not closed, take a look at this and fix it.

Comment: @CalvinNunes should be fixed!